# Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '['

Tags: php, regex

Say I'm making a simple BBCode function using regex, and I want the [color=] tag to stop parsing at the first semicolon to avoid exploits. Now I've seen this question all over stackoverflow, but it never shows how to implement it.

```
$regex = '/\[colour\=/[^;]*/](.*?)\[\/colour\]/is';
$replace = '<span style="color: $1">$2</span>';
```

Why is this giving me the error in the title? I can't figure out regex for the life of me, so I'm really stuck here.

If it helps any, here is the original regex I wanted to implement:

```
/[^;]*/
```

Comment: You should always validate your regular expression first, e.g. on https://regex101.com/#pcre

Answer (score 3):

Escape the slash:

```
$regex = '/\[colour\=\/[^;]*\/](.*?)\[\/colour\]/is';
//            here __^    __^
```

or use another delimiter:

```
$regex = '#\[colour=/[^;]*/](.*?)\[/colour\]#is';
```

But I guess the regex is:

```
$regex = '#\[colour=/[^;]*\](.*?)\[/colour\]#is';
//       backslash here __^
```

According to the replacement part:

```
$regex = '#\[colour=([^;]+)\](.*?)\[/colour\]#is';
$replace = '<span style="color: $1">$2</span>';
```

*Edit according to comment:*

```
$regex = '#\[colour=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/colour\]#is';
$replace = '<span style="color: $1">$2</span>';
```

Comment: None of them seem to work. They all just make the [colour] tag not parse (change into html tags) at all.

Comment: "none seem to work" - then the regex isn't matching anything. So start debugging to find out why.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what you mean by example. The code in my OP is already what I've got.

Comment: That just seemed to create this: `<span style="color: blue]normal test[/colour"> [colour=red;font-size:50pt]test with semicolon</span>`

Comment: `echo parseBBCode('[colour=blue]normal test[/colour] [colour=red;font-size:50pt]test with semicolon[/colour]');` where the parseBBCode function is pretty much what I showed in the OP (but with a preg_replace return)

Comment: @sezgtfsdfsd: See my edit, is that what you want?

Comment: That was where I was at the beginning. I want it to only parse up to the first semicolon, not including the semicolon itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet of the code:

```
$text = '[colour=red]Text in red[/colour]';
$regex = '/\[colour=([^;]*)\](.*?)\[\/colour\]/is';
$replace = '<span style="color: $1">$2</span>';

echo preg_replace($regex, $replace, $text);
```